# Get ITextView in OutliningTaggerProvider

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-sdk

So I am trying to provide [outlining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee197665.aspx) . And a part of my code needs a ITextView object in the Tagger provider.

The [IViewTaggerProvider Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.tagging.iviewtaggerprovider.aspx), which gives the ITextView object in its method, shows how to use it for Highlighting etc (if you scroll down on that page), but if I implement this interface instead of ITaggerProvider, outlining breaks.

Is there any way to use IViewTaggerProvider in outlining provider? Or any way to get the ITextView object?